# Primitive Obsession - Strongly typed int ID with auto increment

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

How to get a strongly typed Id...

```
public sealed class FileUploadId
{
    public int Value { get; }

    public FileUploadId(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

...which is used within my `FileUpload` class...

```
public class FileUpload : EntityBase, IAggregateRoot
{
    private FileUpload() { /* Required by EF */ }

    public FileUpload(string name, string relativePath, FileUploadType type, string contentType, long? size = null)
    {
        /* Guard clauses... */

        Id = new FileUploadId(0);

        /* Other properties... */
    }

    public FileUploadId Id { get; }

    /* Other properties... */
}
```

...working with identity (`int` auto increment)?

I tried `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()`in my `TypeConifiguration`, but without success...

```
public class FileUploadTypeConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<FileUpload>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<FileUpload> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasConversion(x => x.Value, x => new FileUploadId(x)).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        /* Other configurations... */
    }
}
```

I know there's another option with the **HiLo algorithm**. But I want to get it work with default `int` id increment. Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Why do you think you need that `FileUploadId` class anyway? If all it's doing is exposing a readonly int property, why not just use a readonly int property on the `FileUpload` class? What benefits does the `FileUploadId` provide?

Comment: It's about "Primitive Obsession". You can read about it here: https://andrewlock.net/using-strongly-typed-entity-ids-to-avoid-primitive-obsession-part-1/

Comment: Thanks, I've learned something new today because of you! I do think, however, that while the points made in the blog post where valid, and the solution proposed is also valid, that this approach might be a massive overkill in many cases.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. In most cases this approach is a overkill. But when you start a new project from scratch which contains a large business domain it could be very helpful for a clean codebase.

Comment: So the idea is to have some primitive values like Primary & Foreign Keys wrapped in a custom class, so the class matching can ask you "why are you trying to assign a CustomerID to a OrderID field/property?" Interesting idea. Could propably make a generic for it.

Comment: As I understand it the issue is assigning that value during Deserialisation and apparently Resultset/EF mapping. Automagics wich first create a empty instance to then asign the values conventionally. Did I get this right?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get strongly typed ids with auto incrementing ints working with .net6 and EFCore6 by:

- Configuring `.HasConversion()`
- Adding `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()`
- Adding `.Metadata.SetBeforeSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore)`
- Making sure the strongly typed id is never null

**Edit:**
There is a pitfall with this approach.

It has to do with the change tracking. Since ef core 3.0 and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14616), when you are using auto incrementing for your key and the key value is not it's default, the entity is added in the 'Modified' state instead of the 'Added' state. This is a problem for the current solution as we never set null for the strongly typed ids. We would have to manually begin tracking the entity in the 'Added' state (with the DbContext Add method) and other types of automatic tracking will not work (for example adding the entity in a navigational property collection for a one-to-many relationship). Official support for this is being tracked with [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11597).

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I call `DbSet.Add(entity)` where the entity has an Id configured as above, I get the exception: `The property 'Entity.Id' does not have a value set and no value generator is available for properties of type 'StrongId'. Either set a value for the property before adding the entity or configure a value generator for properties of type 'StrongId' in 'OnModelCreating'`

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, using strongly-typed variables with SQL in EF is a true pain. The best explanation I have seen can be found in [this blog post by Andrew Lock](https://andrewlock.net/using-strongly-typed-entity-ids-to-avoid-primitive-obsession-part-3/).

The core of the problem? Using strongly-typed values can result in conducting the filtering of a query (the WHERE ID = value clause) on the client, requiring the process to retrieve all of the records from the DB to perform the selection locally.

The core to the solution? Using a ValueConverter to cast the strongly-typed value to the correct SQL Server value.

Details are extensive. See the referenced article for detail on how to do it.

Comment: This actually did not solve my question. My question is not about casting strongly-typed values to natives. I already know Andrews blog series. But he is using always a `Guid` which is generated manually. I just want to use a `int` which is **auto incremented** (not created manually before insert).

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise against letting EF deal with the strongly typed Id. It does not handle it well and there will be cases where it will try to filter things in memory.

But you can have both properties, one for EF queries, and one for everything else.

```
class FileUpload
{
    public int InternalId { get; private set; }
    public FileUploadId Id 
    {
        get { return new FileUploadId(InternalId); }
        set { InternalId = value.Value; }
    }
}
```

It's leaky, but it works.